# string replace in Python 2.7

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 and working on below string replace problem, wondering if any better ideas in terms of algorithm space complexity and algorithm time complexity?

I create an additional list to represent result since string Python 2.7 is immutable and I also created an additional dictionary to speed-up look-up for character replacement table.

In the example, From: `"lod"` and To: `"xpf"` means when met with `l`, replace to `x` ; and when met with `o`, replace to `p`; and when met with `d`, replace to `f`.

```
'''
Given "data", "from", and "to" fields, replaces all occurrences of the characters in the "from" field in the "data" field, with their counterparts in the "to" field.
Example:
Input:
Data: "Hello World"
From: "lod"
To: "xpf"
Output:
"Hexxp Wprxf"
'''

from collections import defaultdict
def map_strings(from_field, to_field, data):
    char_map = defaultdict(str)
    result = []
    for i,v in enumerate(from_field):
        char_map[v]=to_field[i]
    for v in data:
        if v not in char_map:
            result.append(v)
        else:
            result.append(char_map[v])

    return ''.join(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print map_strings('lod', 'xpf', 'Hexxp Wprxf')
```

Comment: [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

Comment: @wwii Note the question is tagged `python-2.7`; the `str.maketrans` method only exists in Python 3, although Python 2 has the slightly different `string.maketrans` function, as I mention in my answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring, aye  ```string.maketrans``` it is.

Comment: @wwii, nice catch, how do you think `str.maketrans` implemented internally? Does it use similar approach like a mapping dictionary as I am using? Or some more efficient ideas?

Comment: ?? some kind of mapping I would guess.

Answer (score 4):

There's efficient machinery in the standard modules for this. You first build a translation table using [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans), then call the [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method:

```
import string

trans = string.maketrans('lod', 'xpf')
print "Hello World".translate(trans)
```

**output**

```
Hexxp Wprxf
```

---

But if you want to do it manually, here's a way that's a little more efficient than your current code:

```
def map_strings(from_field, to_field, data):
    char_map = dict(zip(from_field, to_field))
    return ''.join([char_map.get(c, c) for c in data])

s = map_strings('lod', 'xpf', 'Hello World')
print s
```

---

Note that in Python 3 the `string.maketrans` function no longer exists. There's now a [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) method, with slightly different behaviour.

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring, vote up for your answer. But why you think your method is more efficient than mine? I think we are using the same idea? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `replace`:

```
def map_strings(from_field, to_field, data):
    for f, t in zip(from_field, to_field):
        data = data.replace(f, t)
    return data
```

Comment: Sure, that works, and it may even be more efficient than using `.translate` when `from_field` & `to_field` are very short. But in general it will be less efficient due to making multiple method calls & having to allocate a new string on each loop iteration. `.translate` doesn't have that problem because it can run at C speed manipulating the char data in a way that's not possible in Python, and it only translates the chars that are present in the source string, rather than looping over every char pair in `from_field` & `to_field`.

Comment: Thanks ebeneditos, vote up for your answer. How do you think `replace` works internally? Does it using a mapping dictionary as I did in my original post, or some more efficient ideas?

Comment: @PM2Ring, nice catch, how do you think `.translate` implemented internally? Does it use similar approach like a mapping dictionary as we are using? Or some more efficient ideas?

Comment: @LinMa Sorry, I'm not sure of the details in Python 3, but I _assume_ that a dictionary (or dict-like mapping) is used to do the translation. In Python 2 a simple 256 element array is used. But in either case the translation is being executed in compiled C code, which is invariably faster & more efficient than doing it in interpreted Python code.